Airflow DataprocSubmitPySparkJobOperator Deprecated - use DataprocSubmitJobOperator... how do I run a job on old python version?
Currently upgrading code to execute on Airflow 2.5, from 2.0. I can see in the documentation that the 'DataprocSubmitPySparkJobOperator' is deprecated (though the script still works). I am currently passing this argument to 'DataprocSubmitPySparkJobOperator':
dataproc_properties={'spark.pyspark.python':'/opt/conda/miniconda3/envs/python3.8/bin/python3.8', 'spark.pyspark.driver.python':'/opt/conda/miniconda3/envs/python3.8/bin/python3.8'}

Since it was defined in the documentation here DataprocSubmitPySparkJobOperator - template_fields
However, 'dataproc_properties' is no longer detailed in the source code 'template_fields' for 'DataprocSubmitJobOperator'. Do I now need to use the 'job' option with 'DataprocJobBaseOperator' to pass these parameters? If so, how do I do this?
Thanks
